# Define Words as Variable in Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm trying to define two variables to be used in a bash script but, ONLY the first texts, "em" and "ctl" in the variables are read... I need them all to work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
cores=("em" "nmm" "nmb")
mems=("ctl" "n1" "n2" "n3" "p1" "p2" "p3")

echo "${cores}"
echo "${mems}"
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the whole array, you need to add `[@]` which expands to all elements.

```
echo "${cores[@]}"
echo "${mems[@]}"
```

Comment: @AaronPerry What exactly are you trying to do? Passing the array with [@] to echo works just fine for me.

Comment: I'm trying to use the variable in a wget URL, so each text string in the variable gets read with wget and then moves onto the next text string.

Comment: @AaronPerry You should then ask another question with this specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing it right, but to see everything in the array you need to use

```
echo ${cores[*]}
echo ${mems[*]}
```